# Simple struct alignment/padding question

Tags: c++, memory

I have a 32-bit C++ program here, and was checking disassembly out of curiosity. I have the following struct:

```
struct Blah
{
    char foo;
    std::string bar;
};
```

When accessing blah->bar, I noted the following:

```
; ... address of blah is in eax
003A227B  add         eax,4
```

So my question is, why does 4 needed to be added to `blah`'s address to get to `bar`? I would understand 3, because `char` is 1 byte and that would make a nice round 4...

Comment: And it's adding it to the start of the struct, not the end of foo, which is why it is 4 and not 3.

Comment: ah, duh. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: [Data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is adding 4 to the base address of `blah`.  I guess that is the same as adding 3 to the address just *after* `foo`. :)

It is indeed an alignment issue.  Pointers should be aligned on address which are a multiple of 4.